# Cannot access class inside my library implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to access a class that is inside a .jar file (`dspread-android_sdk_2.6.3.jar`), this .jar file has been implemented by a library project and the library project is being implemented by my main app project.

For any reason I when I sync Gradle everything is ok, but when I click on Run app to test my app the next error is showen in build:

```
error: cannot access QPOSService
class file for com.dspread.xpos.QPOSService not found
```

*I have checked that the class exists inside the .jar file.*

**This is how I implemented the library project in my app build.gradle:**

```
implementation project(":library_project_name")
```

**settings.properties:**

```
include ':app', ':library_project_name'
```

**This is the library project's Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

        //sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        //targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into 'libs'
    include 'dspread-android_sdk_2.6.3.jar'
}
```

**This is how I import the class inside my Activity:**

```
import com.dspread.xpos.QPOSService;
```

Any ideas of why might this be happening??

Comment: try compile project(":library_project_name") instead of 
 implementation project(":library_project_name")

Comment: @Jacks Same problem